# SSL error with java openjdk version "1.8.0_292"

Tags: java, java-8, ubuntu-16.04

Docker services(built using base image ubuntu:16.04), connecting to aws aurora (Mysql based) started failing on 21-Jul-2021. No code change was done, however we had only rebuilt the docker and deployed the service due to some requirement.

Connection to aurora started failing with below error,

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Including useSSL=false in connection string solved the issue.

When we compared the working docker image and error docker image, we found java version updated from openjdk version "1.8.0_252" to openjdk version "1.8.0_292". Looking forward for help to fix this issue.

Comment: This is almost certainly caused by [Java 8 Update 291](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/release_changes.html) disabling TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 by default (leaving only 1.2 and 1.3 enabled) for security reasons. See [this bug entry](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8202343). The safest way is to upgrade the server side to support the latest TLS version.

Comment: Note that MySQL 5.x and MySQL 8.x can be configured to use TLSv1.2 and later; see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html for example.  Indeed, TLSv1 and v1.1 are officially deprecated in MySQL 5.7.35 and MySQL 8.0.26.

Comment: See also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport which notes that TLSv1.2 is supported in all MySQL 8 releases, from MySQL 5.7.21 onwards and MySQL 5.6.46 onwards.

Comment: Thank you, It was indeed issue with TLS version, as Joachim Sauer mentioned TLS1.0/1.1 is no more supported in latest java update. Somehow JPA uses older version for connection. As Stephen C mentioned, we need to use higher version for connection. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_support_for_spring_boot/2.1/html/release_notes_for_spring_boot_2.1/known-issues-spring-boot provides some info on this. Using enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2 in connection string solved the issue